# Resetting the password for Mac OS 9 using a Windows keyboard?

Tags: mac

How can I reset the password on Mac OS 9 with a Windows keyboard?

When I use my Windows keyboard by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>windows</kbd> key + <kbd>s</kbd> I can’t get to text command. Therefore it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl = Control (no duh)

⊞ Windows key = Command ⌘

Alt = Option ⌥

If you are supposed to press option, use Alt. You only tried Command and Control.